# Receiving a [$injector:modulerr] in console when setting up angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

I'm setting up a page using angular.js and am using angular-ui-router and am running into a pretty basic issue which i can't seem to figure out. I have required the proper CDN's and I believe I have setup the angular correctly but am running into a an error:

```
> angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=portfolioApp&p1=Err…oudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)
```

My `app.js` is as follows:

```
> angular.module('portfolioApp', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']).config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) 
>{$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');  
> $stateProvider
>     .state('main', {
>       url: '/',
>       views: {
>         '/': {
>           templateUrl: '/views/main.html'
>         }
>       }
>     });   $locationProvider.html5Mode({
>     enabled: true,
>     requireBase: false   
>  }); 
>}]);
```

my `index.html` file which is located within the main folder of my app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tammer Galal</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-resource.js"></script> -->
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.6/darkly/bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app='portfolioApp' class="portfolioBody">
    <div class="bs-component">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="repo.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Github Repositories<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="repo.html">Repos</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div ui-view><div>
    <!-- <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
      </div>
    </footer> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to load a basic home partial which i have named `partial-home.html` which is within my `public/views/partials` directory path.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <img class="img-rounded me" id="firstPicture" src="/img/me.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div>
        <h3 class="siteHeader"><strong>Rock Paper Scissors!</strong></h3>
        <a href="rps.html"><img class="img-rounded" id="rpsPic" src="/img/rps.jpg"></a>
        <p class="siteDescrip">Play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors! Created utilizing: <br /><strong>HTML, CSS3, Javascript, and jQuery</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <h3 class="siteHeader"><strong>Face Check</strong></h3>
      <a href="http://face-check.herokuapp.com/"><img class="img-rounded" id="faceCheckPic" src="/img/faceCheckPic.jpg"></a>
      <p class="siteDescrip">A facial and emotional recognition app Created utilizing: <br /><strong>HTML, CSS3, Javascript, jQuery, AJAX, and 3 APIs</strong><br /><strong>Co-Creators: Long Phan and Evan Bates</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <h3 class="siteHeader"><strong>RU Fly?</strong></h3>
      <a href="http://rufly2.herokuapp.com/"><img class="img-rounded" id="faceCheckPic" src="/img/rufly.jpg"></a>
      <p class="siteDescrip">RU Fly is a Rutgers Web Flyer, where students can add their favorite restaurants and leave reviews, so everyone knows the best place to eat! Adding upcoming events soon!<br /><strong>HTML, CSS3, Javascript, Node.js, MySQL, Sequelize, Express, JawsDB</strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I really cannot figure out what it is i have done wrong and am thinking about starting from scratch. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add `ng-strict-di` to your `body` element with the `ng-app` attribute.  `ng-strict-di` will enforce Dependency Injection and give you a more detailed error about which Dependency isn't being properly supplied.  Just by looking at it though, I would make a guess that it is `ui.bootstrap` that is a problem.

Comment: changed to `  <body ng-app='portfolioApp' class="portfolioBody" ng-strict-di>` and am still receiving the same console log error. Will remove `ui-bootstrap` now and check back in 2 minutes. ***Update*** Removing `ui-bootstrap` fixed the issue! thank you so much.

Comment: Creating a quick plunker to reproduce your issue, my suspicion is confirmed.  changing to angular.js instead of angular.min.js reveals `Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available!`

Comment: in general, you should use `angular.js` in development for more detailed error messages, and `angular.min.js` in production.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this error. Everything works fine, but when I added 'ui.bootstrap' module in app 'portfolioApp', same error message displayed. Also, I am not seeing any reference for 'ui.bootstrap' module in your 'index.html'. Try to remove 'ui.bootstrap' or add reference of this module in 'index.html'.